# Optional Parent-Child relationship

Tags: database-design, referential-integrity

I have a problem modeling a relationship whereby the child may or may not be related to a parent. For example. You have a Band database with a Tour(parent) table, and a Gig/Concert(child) table. Now, a Tour is a compilation of 1 or more Gigs, but a Gig may also be held off-tour. How do i model this without violating referential integrity?

E.G Tables:

```
    create table Tour(
    tourID int primary key,
    ...//
    );

    create table Gig(
    gigID int primary key,
    tourID int,
    ...//
    foreign key(tourID) references Tour.tourID
    );
```

PS: Newbie here

Answer (score 2):

Just make the Tour optional?   The below code is for SQL Server, but you should be able to port this to other flavors of SQL.  Essentially, the `TourID` column can be nullable, indicating the `Gig` is not part of a `Tour`.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Bands
(
    BandID INT NOT NULL
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    , BandName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Tours
(
    TourID INT NOT NULL
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    , TourName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.Gigs
(
    GigID INT NOT NULL
    , GigName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
    , GiGDate DATETIME NOT NULL
    , BandID INT NOT NULL
        FOREIGN KEY
        REFERENCES dbo.Bands(BandID)
    , TourID INT NULL
        FOREIGN KEY 
        REFERENCES dbo.Tours(TourID)
);
```

This design will also allow multiple bands to take part in any given tour, thereby providing a mechanism for headliners and opening acts, or multi-stage events, etc.

Filling out the example from above with some data:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Bands (BandID, BandName)
VALUES (1, 'Past the Perimeter');

INSERT INTO dbo.Tours (TourID, TourName)
VALUES (1, 'Taking it to the City');

INSERT INTO dbo.Gigs (GigID, GigName, GiGDate, BandID, TourID)
VALUES (1, 'Tour Date 1', '2016-05-27T21:30:00', 1, 1);

INSERT INTO dbo.Gigs (GigID, GigName, GiGDate, BandID, TourID)
VALUES (2, 'Standalone Gig', '2016-05-28T21:30:00', 1, NULL);

SELECT b.BandName
    , g.GigName
    , g.GiGDate
    , t.TourName
FROM dbo.Bands b
    INNER JOIN dbo.Gigs g ON b.BandID = g.BandID
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Tours t ON g.TourID = t.TourID
ORDER BY g.GiGDate;
```

[image]